# How to merge a git pull request from a sibling fork?

Tags: git

In git, how do you merge changes into your fork of a repo made in a separate fork?

For example, say I've forked git repo A onto my local repo B. Someone later forced repo A onto their repo C and created a pull request to repo A. How do I merge that pull request on my repo B?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Pull Request is not a Git feature, but specific to repository hosting providers, such as GitHub. Pull Requests are usually not transferable/copyable (not for GitHub anyway).

What you can do is merge the underlying branch of a Pull Request. A Pull Request is about merging from `someremote/somebranch` to `otherremote/otherbranch`. If you know `someremote/somebranch`, you can add a remote in your local Git repo, and merge `someremote/somebranch`.

So in your example, you can add a remote for repo B, fetch, and merge the branch that was in the Pull Request going from `repoB/somebranch` to `repoA/master`. Something like this:

```
git remote add repoB url_to_repo_B
git fetch repoB somebranch
git merge repoB/somebranch
```

Comment: Interesting read on merging PR: https://ericjmritz.name/2015/06/22/why-and-how-i-avoid-githubs-merge-pull-request-feature/